# spring boot + splunk

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, splunk

I have a spring boot app which writes to a log file and uses  a splunk forwarder. Everything works fine and my logs appear on splunk. when i upgrade from spring boot version 2.2.5 to spring boot 2.3.4. My logs do not get pushed to splunk.

I have tried downgrading, and the logs start getting pushed to splunk again.

here is a snippet of my yml which handles logging config

```
logging:
  file: myLogs.log
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web:
          filter:
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
```

Comment: try removing the version line of spring boot in pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was after upgrading spring boot you now need to use a yml structure like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web:
          filter:
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
  file:
    name: server.log
```

Not forgetting that your java arg for
`-Dlogging`
needs to change from
-`Dlogging.file`
to
 `-Dlogging.file.name`